# Table-Valued Parameter Recieving Invalid Data Type Error

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, table-valued-parameters

I have an array of data from a console app I've developed that I need to transfer into a SQL database. As SQL injections are volatile, I decided to try passing it through a stored procedure via table-valued parameter. I created the table type with no issues and it is listed under 'User-Defined Table Types' folder. The issue I am having is when I try to create my stored procedure, I receive this error:

> Msg 2715, Level 16, State 3, Procedure sp_IsertBackupData, Line 2
>   [Batch Start Line 0] Column, parameter, or variable #1: Cannot find
>   data type VeeamTableType. Parameter or variable '@VeeamTableType' has
>   an invalid data type.

Does anyone have any insight on what could be the issue here?

I have already tried refreshing the local cache.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_IsertBackupData

@VeeamTableType VeeamTableType READONLY 

AS 

BEGIN

    DECLARE @q varchar(1000)
    SET @q= 'SELECT * FROM' + @VeeamTableType


    INSERT INTO ASManagement.dbo.VeeamBackupResults 
    (
    Id, 
    Server,
    BackupLogFileName,
    BackupLogFileSize,
    CreatedOn 
    )

    EXEC (@q)

END


SELECT * FROM ASManagement.VeeamBackupResults

CREATE TYPE VeeamBackupResults.VeeamTableType as TABLE

(

    Id int primary key,

    Server varchar(500) null,

    BackupLogFileName varchar (500) null, 

    BackupLogFileSize float null, 

    CreatedOn datetime null

)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root cause of appearing the error is the stored Procedure cannot find `VeeamTableType` because **you create it under `VeeamBackupResults` schema** and you are trying to create the Procedure under default schema (`dbo` at most of you dose not change the default to be another one )

So for fixing the error, you should follow one of next solutions:-

1) Create procedure under the `VeeamBackupResults` schema

**Try** `CREATE PROCEDURE VeeamBackupResults.sp_IsertBackupData`

**instead of** `CREATE PROCEDURE sp_IsertBackupData`

Or 2) pass `VeeamTableType` with its correct schema

**Try:** `@VeeamTableType VeeamBackupResults.VeeamTableType READONLY`

**instead of:** `@VeeamTableType VeeamTableType READONLY`

Or 3) Create the user definde table variable into default schema

**Try:** `CREATE TYPE VeeamTableType as TABLE`

**instead of:** `CREATE TYPE VeeamBackupResults.VeeamTableType as TABLE`

Comment: Glad to help you.

Comment: Plz flag this answer as accepted one. https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 0):

You need no dynamic sql

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_IsertBackupData   
      @VeeamTableType VeeamTableType READONLY 
AS    
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO ASManagement.dbo.VeeamBackupResults 
    (
      Id, 
      Server,
      BackupLogFileName,
      BackupLogFileSize,
      CreatedOn 
    )
    SELECT * 
    FROM @VeeamTableType;
END
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=00e681d077a545fa7c16ccdd2fee4cef) to create proc

Comment: That doesn't really help the issue.

Comment: See fiddle. Compiles OK.